# Webpack content security policy problem with loadCSS

Tags: reactjs, webpack, content-security-policy

I'm trying to implement a strict csp with an existing production project

The problem I am currently facing is that something is injecting the following:

- PostCSS javascript inline

```js
!function(n){"use strict";n.loadCSS||(n.loadCSS=function(){});var t,o=loadCSS.relpreload={};o.support=function(){var e;try{e=n.document.createElement("link").relList.supports("preload")}catch(t){e=!1}return function(){return e}}(),o.bindMediaToggle=function(t){var e=t.media||"all";function a(){t.addEventListener?t.removeEventListener("load",a):t.attachEvent&&t.detachEvent("onload",a),t.setAttribute("onload",null),t.media=e}t.addEventListener?t.addEventListener("load",a):t.attachEvent&&t.attachEvent("onload",a),setTimeout(function(){t.rel="stylesheet",t.media="only x"}),setTimeout(a,3e3)},o.poly=function(){if(!o.support())for(var t=n.document.getElementsByTagName("link"),e=0;e<t.length;e++){var a=t[e];"preload"!==a.rel||"style"!==a.getAttribute("as")||a.getAttribute("data-loadcss")||(a.setAttribute("data-loadcss",!0),o.bindMediaToggle(a))}},o.support()||(o.poly(),t=n.setInterval(o.poly,500),n.addEventListener?n.addEventListener("load",function(){o.poly(),n.clearInterval(t)}):n.attachEvent&&n.attachEvent("onload",function(){o.poly(),n.clearInterval(t)})),"undefined"!=typeof exports?exports.loadCSS=loadCSS:n.loadCSS=loadCSS}("undefined"!=typeof global?global:this);
```

- Css links are being rewriten with event handlers which is prohibited by csp rules (there is a nonce with a valid value (nonce has the string because I am inspecting source map)

```css
<link rel="preload" href="/semantic.min.css" nonce="FBg3Hiw1fPw82wI+ZTQ1FA==" as="style" onload="this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'">
<link rel="preload" href="/css/styles.4387bdcc2b511fc0275c.443131ae.css" nonce="FnleNIaDpf5weHCTp/owTA==" as="style" onload="this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'">
```

My question is

- how can I make the loadCSS script (which I dont really know where he comes from but I have a guess which is from postCSS parser )
- How can I stop my css files getting rewriten with inline event handlers, this one I dont really know who is responsible for the overwrite

Below I will also add the webpack configs relevat to the subject in hands, and of course if more information is needed please feel free to ask.

- Parsers

```js
{
                test: /\.less$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true,
                            localsConvention: "camelCase",
                            modules: {
                                localIdentName: "[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:5]",
                            },
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "less-loader",
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                    },
                ],
            },
```

- Plugins

```js
new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: "./ClientApp/src/index.ejs",
            inject: false,
            favicon: "./ClientApp/src/assets/images/favicon.ico",
            templateParameters: (compilation, assets) => {
                const css =
                    assets
                        .css
                        .map((filePath) => `<link rel="stylesheet" href="${filePath}" />`).join("\n");
                const js = 
                    assets
                        .js
                        .map((filePath) => `<script src="${filePath}"></script>`).join("\n");
                return { css, js };
            },
        }),
        new CspHtmlWebpackPlugin({
            'script-src': ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'"],
            'style-src': ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'"],
            'img-src': "'self' data:",
            'font-src': "'self' data:",
            'object-src': "'none'",
            'frame-src': "'self'",
            'base-uri': "'self'",
            'form-action': "'self'",
            'manifest-src': "'self'",
            'default-src': "'self'",
            'connect-src': "'self' {{app-url}}",
        }, {
            enabled: true,
            hashingMethod: 'sha256',
            hashEnabled: {
                'script-src': true,
                'style-src': true
            },
            nonceEnabled: {
                'script-src': true,
                'style-src': true
            },
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "./css/styles.[hash].css",
            stats: "none",
            ignoreOrder: true,

        }),
```

I have tried using ExtractTextPlugin instead of MiniCssExtractPlugin, with no luck.

Tried to write the styles and javascript imports with the templateParameters from HtmlWebPackPlugin

I have also tried to remove those handlers with a js script in index.cjs which does work for the second question, but I am sure there is a better way somehow.

```js
<script>
        let stylesheets = document.querySelectorAll('link[onload]');
        for (let i = 0; i < stylesheets.length; i++) {
            stylesheets[i].onload = null;
            stylesheets[i].rel = 'stylesheet';
            stylesheets[i].as = '';
        }
    </script>
```